# @IBAction Swift confusion

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder

I made an IBAction from Interface Builder as normal with a ctrl-Click drag. Filled in the relevant information and was left with.

```
@IBAction func setNameLable(sender: AnyObject) {
   println("test")
}
```

This worked initially, but I then noticed my spelling mistake in the function name and went back and corrected it. Needless to say the next time I run this I had an error which I fixed by relinking the "Touch Up Inside" action to my new function as follows.

```
@IBAction func setNameLabel(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("test")
}
```

Now when I click the button it does not fire.

I made a new button and linked that to the same function and it also doesn't fire.

If I add any character to the name of my function i.e "setNameLabel1" and relink it works fine. It is just that specific function name that is not working.

What is causing this?

[image]

Comment: if you are modifying de name of the "function".. then you have to "relink" the Outlet - every time

Comment: It is relinked. I have tested this exact function with a character appended on the end of its name. Relinked it, saw it work, changed it back relinked it and it doesn't fire. My screenshots shows that the @IBAction is configured to the UIButton's "Touch Up Inside" event.

Comment: :) yes, you have right! There is a conflict between `nameLabel` and `setNameLabel`

Comment: Ok, I just changed the nameLabel to nameLabelField and it worked. So my next question is, does swift reserve get<name> and set<name> as getters and setters of properties by default?

Comment: for nothing! I did not notice this before, maybe someone else has the answer :)